# how re-expand tree grid node if it is expanded?

Tags: extjs, expand, treegrid

On my treegrid when I expanded tree node if there is not data available(and if I added data into database later) I can't expand this node again. need to refresh page. how can I set it expandable? or how force treegrid node to send request again on expand?

Comment: On expand of node you can fire a request to get latest data and can set data on store again.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, all you have to do is update node (expanded) data. This can be done as follows:

```
this.getStore('MyTreeStore').load({ node: someNode});
```